# Why is my parsed image link comming out in base64 format

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, base64

i was trying to parse a image link from a website.
When i inspect the link on the website, it is this one :https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/df7c2668-f714-4ced-9f8f-1f0024f945a9/chaussure-de-basketball-zoom-freak-3-MZpJZF.png but when i parse it with my code the output is `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/fr/w/hommes-chaussures-nik1zy7ok').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

pair = soup.find('div', class_='product-card__body')

image_scr = pair.find('img', class_='css-1fxh5tw product-card__hero-image')['src']
print(image_scr)
```

I think the code isn't the issue but i don't know what's causing the link to come out in base64 format. So how could i set the code to render the link as .png ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

First at all, take a look into your `soup` - There is the truth. Website provides not all information static, there are a lot things provided dynamically and also done by the browser -> So `requests` wont get this info this way.

#### Workaround

Take a look at the `<noscript>` next to your selection, it holds a smaller version of the image and is providing the `src`

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/fr/w/hommes-chaussures-nik1zy7ok').content

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

pair = soup.find('div', class_='product-card__body')

image_scr = pair.select_one('noscript img.css-1fxh5tw.product-card__hero-image')['src']
print(image_scr)
```

#### Output

https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_318,f_auto/t_product_v1/df7c2668-f714-4ced-9f8f-1f0024f945a9/chaussure-de-basketball-zoom-freak-3-MZpJZF.png

If you like a "big picture" just replace parameter `w_318` with `w_1000`...

### Edit

Concerning your comment - There are a lot more solutions, but still depending on what you like to do with the information and what you gonna work with.

Following approache uses `selenium` that is unlike `requests` rendering the website and give you the "right page source" back but also needs more resources then `requests`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.nike.com/fr/w/hommes-chaussures-nik1zy7ok')

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

pair = soup.find('div', class_='product-card__body')

image_scr = pair.select_one('img.css-1fxh5tw.product-card__hero-image')['src']
print(image_scr)
```

#### Output

https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/df7c2668-f714-4ced-9f8f-1f0024f945a9/chaussure-de-basketball-zoom-freak-3-MZpJZF.png

Comment: Hey i just saw that the quality of the image with the link from <noscript> is not so good compared to the one in the 'img' paragraph...is there another way ?

Comment: Thats why I wrote "holds a smaller version of the image" :) But do not worry, I added two   alternativ approaches , take a look

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just did that but it's weird. It seims like all the links parsed after the scroller i made (using webdriver) are in base64 format again...
Last one on the non-scrolled page : 
Nike Air Huarache
124,99 €
https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/e5880da8-24fa-4b12-9362-821692416d49/chaussure-air-huarache-pour-8bzFjr.png
First on the scrolled page :
Nike Air Max 1 x Patta
124,99 €
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

Comment: As often, it depends - Heard of eager or lazy loading, that is what happens, just play around with selenium (await, scrolling, ...) if stuck, ask another question. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to grab src meaning image data, so  downloading data from server using requests, you need to use `.content` format as follows:

```
source = requests.get('https://www.nike.com/fr/w/hommes-chaussures-nik1zy7ok').content
```

Comment: Hey, event with this modification i still get the same issue...`src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7".`